# Request spec error when updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to test my rails project with rspec and am having some difficulty, I'm trying to write a request spec that updates a product and it just doesn't seem to work:

Here is my test:

```
  it 'updates a product' do
    put :update, id: @product, product: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:product, title: "New Title")
    @product.reload
    @product.title.should eq("New Title")
  end
```

and here is the error I get:

```
   Failure/Error: put :update, id: @product, product: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:product, title: "New Title")

     URI::InvalidURIError:
       bad URI(is not URI?): http://www.example.com:80update
```

Any help on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look at your url. This error doesn't have to do with file uploading, your code isn't reaching the upload step.

Comment: Does it work if you use "put '/update'" ? http://www.example.com:80update is missing the slash, what rspec version are you using? is it a controller spec?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set up `@product`? It's not shown in your code. If not, then the problem could be that the id param in your PUT request is nil. If `@product` is already set up, did you try using `id: @product.id` instead of `id: @product`?